# PowerShell * ConvertTo-HTML * Set-CellColor

Tags: html, powershell

I am running a PS code that Converts the results to **HTML** and **highlights** the values **True** in the column named **Enabled** to **Green** if found.

```
Set-CellColor -Property Enabled -Color Green -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'"
```

the results are working:

[image]

What I want is to do the same for the **Locked** column so I modified the code to:

```
 Set-CellColor -Property Enabled -Color Green -Filter "Enabled -eq 'True'" | Set-CellColor -Property Locked -Color Red -Filter "Locked -eq 'True'" |
```

The results are these:

[image]

It works somewhat and colors **Red** the **True** in the **Locked** column but, unfortunate the modified code also changes the color of the cell for the **Enabled** Column also to **Red**.

I need to leave the **green** cell in the **Enabled** column as is and just color **Red** the **True** in the **Locked** column. Can any one tell me what I am coding incorrectly.

Regards,

Comment: Try switching the invocations.

Comment: @Ansgar, I tried your suggestion and it did not work. Now both cells are colored Green instead of Green/Red.

Comment: Then you need to modify the function to do what you want.

Comment: This is a bug in the function you are using, the same author has published ConvertTo-AdvHtml which eventually has not this bug or as an alternative you could use EnhancedHTML.

Comment: @Olaf Reitz Thank you for pointing me to both the ConvertTo-AdvHtml and EnhancedHTML. I will take a look at these and hopefully resolve this.